# How to fix the white screen issue in ionic 2?

Tags: ionic2, splash-screen

I have removed a default splash screen from my ionic 2 app. But it shows a white screen for 5 sec when i have tested it in mobile. In browser, It works fine. How to fix this issue?

Comment: I had same issue, since last 6 month there is nothing solution. kindly share solution if anybody has. And this issue is now rejecting my app from Apple store

Answer (score 0):

There are several preferences related to splashscreens in config.xml, and one of them is about the display delay:

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000"/>
```

But even if you put 0 as the value for the delay, you would have a blank screen for a few seconds, the time for your mobile to load the app and fire the deviceready event. The splashscreen plugin (and other native functionnalities) is anyway not displayed when working on browser, so you cannot based your app dehavior based on that.

Last point, Ionic Team is full aware that the Ionic 2 app have a quite long loading time (actually 5sec is pretty decent), and they are working on this. You can find additional information about this topic here: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-2-speed-up-boot-time/46372/157

Answer (score 0):

inside your config.xml file add this code then you will not face this error.

```
<preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
    </feature>
```

Comment: Actually, I don't want native splash screen. So i removed it. I have an animated splash screen with HTML and CSS. My issue is, a white screen shows up before an animated splash screen.So, I want to hide that white screen. How to fix it?

Comment: then you have to do it in photo shop only because if the image it self like this then we can not do anything if the app is in white screen for 5sec then use the above code @Dheena

Comment: Okay. Thank you @Mohan Gopi